# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm running "npm install node-sass" from git-bash-cli in Windows 10 and getting a "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error.

I have been using this setup for years and the issues started when I upgraded node to 10.16.0

To prevent unnecessary replies:

All the questions I have seen simply say to add the path variable.

I have added Node to the PATH variable and tried a number of different ways of writing it. I ended up reinstalling Node.js and that does it automatically, so I just left it as that.

node runs from the command line, just not from scripts, like scripts in the package.json file.

I have tried reinstalling node 8.11.3, which is the version I was using before the problems started, but I get the same error. I am back to v 10.16.0 again.

Error code is as follows:

```
> node-sass@4.12.0 install C:\projects\true\true\website\truevue\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T23_41_06_896Z-debug.log
```

Here's the log when I run `npm run dev` on a Vue project I'm working on

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2-next.1
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~predev: thisistrue.co@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: thisistrue.co@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\projects\true\true\website\truevue\node_modules\.bin
9 verbose lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: CWD: C:\projects\true\true\website\truevue
10 silly lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server' ]
11 silly lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle thisistrue.co@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: thisistrue.co@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:317:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid thisistrue.co@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\projects\true\true\website\truevue
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Peter\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2-next.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error thisistrue.co@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the thisistrue.co@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Check the file at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T23_41_06_896Z-debug.log and see if there's any additional info in the logs.

Comment: What about checking if you need elevated permission to install.

Comment: @mwilson there's around 4000 lines in the file, but I can't see anything that helps

Comment: @JimmyShoe just checked that by reinstalling node as administrator, but I think that it needs admin permissions to install anyway. Either way, it still doesn;t work

Comment: Just to clarify, you are receiving this error when you run a `script` in your `package.json`? So, for example, if you run `npm run start` or something, that throws the exception?

Comment: @mwilson that seems to be what's happening, but only if the script needs to run node

Comment: See above for an error log when I run `npm run dev`

Comment: OK, `npm run dev` seems to run in Windows Powershell. Maybe an issue with git bash?

Comment: Yea, try it in standard windows command window or something. Node might just not be recognized by bash, but everything is else is good. In that case, I believe bash might require an additional step to pick up the path variable

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer to this.
All I ended up doing was running `npm update -g` and it fixed the issue

Thanks all who helped, hope this can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the path of node.js to the system variable

First: open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Second: in "User variables" or "System variables" find variable PATH and add node.js folder path as value.it is C:\Program Files\nodejs;If it doesn't exists, create it.

Third: Restart  your computer.